# How to install Java Netbeans plugin test my code

Tags: java, netbeans, plugins, netbeans-plugins

I am learning java from [mooc.fi](http://mooc.fi/courses/2013/programming-part-1/) and I need this plugin called ["Test My Code"](https://github.com/testmycode/tmc-netbeans) but I don't know how to install it on Netbeans, I already downloaded and extracted the files but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: There is a README.markdown file in the provides link that contains the information about setup the plugin in netbeans. Read that file and follow.Here is the [link](https://github.com/testmycode/tmc-netbeans/blob/master/README.markdown).

Answer (score 0):

The mooc brings you through an installation guide on how to setup your environment here: https://www.mooc.fi/en/installation/netbeans